# jQuery document ready function how to stop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i add this code in my php script then page is not fully loaded images are also not fully load and refresh automatic again and again ... how i can fix this without removing this code. please fix this issue . i get data from calender but after adding this code i can't select the any date because of page refresh or never fully lodded. can some one fix it if open page then page is fully lodded and stop the refresh automatic

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#showdraw").submit();
});
```

Comment: You're submitting a form everytime the page loads, which reloads the page. Only way to fix that is to remove that piece of code.

Comment: you're submitting a form on the document ready, so it will submit infinitely if it is submitting to the same page. you cannot stop this unless you remove or change the code.

Comment: You probably shouldn't add code to your page if you don't understand how it works.

Comment: how change the code @PlantTheIdea

Comment: @user3421601 That code *pretty much* only restarts the page since anything else doesn't matter if the page can't be visited, so you can't really *change* it.  It would need to be removed and replaced with something that happens after a specific action.

Comment: @user3421601 - i know that's all you care about, but what you're asking for is impossible without changing what calls the submit function. its like asking "I want to get to a point 10 miles away without moving, how can i do it".

Comment: @PlantTheIdea i have script if i open the page then i get data from cureent date by selecting date.. some one tell me about this code so i add this code then my get the data without pressing any key but page can't fully loaded ..so there is another method that i get data from mysql database of current date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how i can fix this without removing this code

You fix this *by* removing this code.  You haven't shown the markup for the `#showdraw` form, but based on the description it sounds like the form is set to POST (or perhaps GET, I suppose) back to the same server-side resource which produces this page.

Thus, you're *explicitly* telling the page to POST the form every time it loads.  You'd fix this by *not* telling the page to POST the form every time it loads.

What you *probably* want to do is remove this code entirely.  Why did you add it in the first place?  What were you trying to accomplish?  It only does *one thing* and you're asking how to make it not do that thing.

You *could* wrap this client-side code in a server-side conditional of some sort, only emitting it under specific conditions.  For example, if you don't want it to be emitted to the page in the event of a form POST then you can check for POST values before emitting it:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
?>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showdraw").submit();
});
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: here is any other option . i have script see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429180/when-i-open-the-page-then-i-want-to-get-the-data-from-database-of-current-date-i and give me answer

Comment: @dvaid i have script if i open the page then i get data from cureent date by selecting date.. some one tell me about this code so i add this code then my get the data without pressing any key but page can't fully loaded ..so there is another method that i get data from mysql database of current date

Comment: @user3421601: Well, you can make an AJAX request to get data from the server without reloading the whole page.  Any PHP+AJAX tutorial can walk you through that.  Of course, if you want to get server-side data when the page loads, you don't really *need* to do any of that.  Your server-side PHP code can fetch the data from the database and render it directly to the page.  (Even if you used AJAX, you'd still be using the same PHP code to do this.)

Comment: so what code i add in my script here is link of my script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429180/when-i-open-the-page-then-i-want-to-get-the-data-from-database-of-current-date-i

Comment: @user3421601: Well, you'd start with a tutorial on PHP, including JavaScript/AJAX if you're intent on using that.  I'm afraid I can't write all of your code for you.

Comment: if i open the page and press the calender button then i get data from database of current date but i want this that data show automatic of current date.